# How to replace caller name while phone is in ringing state?

Tags: android, android-contacts

The phone is in `IDLE` state.

**Mom** is calling -> Phone is in `RINGING` state.

Knowing **Mom**'s number, can I replace **Mom** and instead show **Dad** as a value to the person calling me?

**What am i doing:**

I know **Mom**'s number is **112233445566**. When I receive a call from this number, I make a query to get the caller's name (**Mom**). Then I replace **Mom** with **Dad**.

**Some code:**

```
String[] queryProjection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID
    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };


Uri displayContactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("112233445566"));

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(displayContactUri, queryProjection, null, null, null);

String  callerID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
  ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));


        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
                    .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withSelection(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                    new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(callerID),                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE });
            builder.withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    "Dad");
            ops.add(builder.build());
            try {
                  getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                        ops);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I suspect one possible problem: For the time my code is executed it is already too late and the incoming calling activity is started. Even though I update the value, the caller name is already showing the old name (**Mom**). After the call is finished, I check my Contact book and it is updated as i wanted: **Dad**, number: **112233445566**

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to change the value when it's running, specially because it's not your activity but you can show something on top of the default activity.

Comment: @Shivam Verma I am trying to update the **Contact**, not the value itself in the incoming calling activity. The incoming activity uses the Contact book's content so display who is calling you. So if I manage to update the contact right before the incoming activity shows I will achieve what I want. I am not sure if there is enough time for my code to execute and make the change before the calling activity takes place. :)

Comment: Well, You already know the problem with your own approach :) But you can still display an overlay.